# AngularJS - ngrepeat form input elements dynamically filled with default values to post

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-init

http://jsfiddle.net/9sCnC/12/#

I'm going through a json file and parsing it through ng-repeat, a button on each item opening a modal window. 
In this window a form is generated with data I would like to put into another data array which will be send through post to a php file...

```
  <div ng-repeat="value in model.values">
  <input type="text" ng-model="model.values[$index]" />
 </div>
        <hr>
        <!--Details content Begin-->
        <div class="circle-list">
                           <div class="circle-list-item" ng-repeat="course in courses | filter:query | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:Type" ng-mouseenter="hover(course)" ng-mouseleave="hover(course)">   

                               <span class="btn-xs pull-right">
                                    <span id="Time" class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> {{course.duur}}u
                                </span>

                               <a id="course.Id" title="{{course.NoEDA}}" href="{{course.link}}">{{course.titel | lowercase}}</a>
                               <span id="Type" class="ng-class:course.type">{{course.type}}</span>

                               <span ng-show="course.showOverlay" class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalSubscribe{{$index}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
                                    <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button> -->
                                    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                               </span>


                                    <div class="modal fade" id="ModalSubscribe{{$index}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalSubscribe" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                                <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> Inschrijven</h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                  <!-- SHOW ERROR/SUCCESS MESSAGES -->
                                  <!--
                                  <div id="messages" ng-show="message" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errormail }">{{ message }}</div>
                                  -->
                                    <div id="messages" class="alert alert-success" data-ng-show="message" >{{ message }}</div>
                                    <div id="messages" class="alert alert-danger" data-ng-show="errormessage" >{{ errormessage }}</div>

                                    <form id="register" name="register" class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="processForm()">
                                    <div id="name-group" class="form-group">
                                      <!-- EDA -->
                                      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Opleiding:</label>
                                      <div class="col-sm-10 controls"> 

                                          <input type="text" name="eda[]" class="form-control" value="{{course.NoEDA}}" ng-model="course.NoEDA"> 


                                      </div>
                                      <!-- Name -->
                                      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Naam:</label>
                                      <div class="col-sm-10 controls">
                                        <input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Naam" ng-model="formData.name">
                                      </div>
                                      <!-- Matricule -->
                                      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Stamnumer:</label>
                                      <div class="col-sm-10 controls">
                                        <input type="number" name="matricule[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Stamnummer" ng-model="formData.matricule">
                                      </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <!--<legend>Email</legend>-->
                                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': errormail}">
                                      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email:</label>
                                      <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
                                        <input type="email" name="[]mail" class="form-control" data-ng-model="formData.mail" placeholder="mail"/>
                                      </div>
                                      <!--<span class="help-block" ng-show="errormail">{{ errormail }}</span>-->
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.agree1" name="Agreement1[]" required />
                                    Ik ben akkoord
                                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.agree2" name="Agreement2[]" required />
                                    Ik ga akkoord
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Sluit</button>
                                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-enabled="{{register.mail}}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>&nbsp;Inschrijven</button>
                                </div>
                                  </form> 
                                {{ formData }}
                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div> 





                                <!-- temp, later wel plaatsen
                                <span class="label label-default">{{course.Departement}}</span>
                                -->
                                <small>
                                    <br/><i id="placelabel" class="text-muted"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> {{course.plaats || "-"}}</i>
                                    <i id="placename" class="text-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> {{course.organisatie || "-"}}</i>
                                    <small id="public" class="pull-right"><br /><i class="doelgroep">{{course.doelgroep}}</i></small>
                                </small>
                           </div>
       </div>
       <!--Details content End-->
</div>
<!--container content End-->
```

What I don't understand is:

```
ng-init="formData.eda=course.NoEDA"    is putting the last item in the array I guess

value="{{course.NoEDA}}"  this is showing the good item array
```

how do I transfer the right item from course.NoEDA to another ng-model formData.eda?

I'm just starting with this, if I'm doing this the wrong way please help me out here...
my fiddle isn't working at all but on my local server everything is working except passing the values to post them...

thanks in advance...